# Is there a way to export sphinxneeds needtable to Excel?

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx

Is there a way to export the sphinxneeds needtable to Excel without pressing the Excel button?

The image below shows the example of the generated sphinxneeds needtable with a button that exports the sphinxneeds into Excel:

[image: Sphinxneeds table example]

Is there an option during generation to export the sphinxneeds needtable to Excel without having to manually export using the Excel button?